# JavaScript equality operators: Is there a use-case in which I should prefer == over ===?

Tags: javascript

Authors and developers seem to agree that one should use the === operator which checks the value AND the type.

But I ask myself:
It's in the language. So there most the a reason why!

Therefore my question (to the more experienced JavaScript developer):

Can anyone show me a szenarios in which I would profit from using the == operator?

Or explain me the reason why it is in the language?

Comment: IMO, no, always use `===` and `!==`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons?rq=1

Comment: If you want `'0'==0` to be evaluated as `true`!

Comment: please go through http://stackoverflow.com/questions/523643/difference-between-and-in-javascript

Comment: When you're not sure about the datatype of a variable and compare it with another, ex. zero(_I don't know if this is string or number_) comparing with string/number zero.

Comment: @Tushar Exactly that's what I have meant. Their most the cases in practical usage where it is useful. Or it is error when creating the language. But there most be people who know about that. Therefore I asked ...

Comment: you need == when you compare something from HTML attributes, because HTML attributes are always strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For instance, when you need to compare an object with a primitive type:

```
new String("abc") === "abc"
```

Will return `false`, so it's better to use `==` for this kind of scenario.

```
new String("abc") == "abc"
```

Will return `true`.

Comment: This is one of the _reason_, not the _only_ reason...

Comment: @Rayon Please: What are the other reasons?

Comment: Now we just need a reason to use `new String` in the first place...

Comment: @st88, _"JavaScript has two sets of equality operators: === and !==, and their evil twins == and !=. The good ones work the way you would expect. If the two operands are of the same type and have the same value, then === produces true and !== produces false. The evil twins do the right thing when the operands are of the same type, but if they are of different types, they attempt to coerce the values. the rules by which they do that are complicated and unmemorable."_ [[Reference](http://stackoverflow.com/a/359509/1746830)]

Comment: To be frank, this is a horrible example. It's more a display of why you should really never be using `new String`. The function `String` should be called, not used as a constructor.

Answer (score 1):

### "Because it's easier"

I'm pretty sure the behavior for double equals was designed to lower the bar for people learning the language. In nearly every case, there's no good reason to use double equals over triple except to save a bit of typing.

Triple is faster and safer. It doesn't do any "magic". Magic sucks. Magic is less predictable.

That said, how double equals works is well known, and isn't doing *that much* magic. It's simply casting to the nearest primitive type, and you might consider one use case for it to be comparing an input string with a number value.

e.g., `quantityInput.value == 0`

An obvious issue with this would in cases where quantityInput is empty or not a number. But, this issue would arise with triple equals, too. So, ignoring those cases, the same thing using triple-equals would be:

`Number(quantityInput.value) === 0` or `+(quantityInput.value) === 0`

The intentions of the triple equal examples are more clear. We're taking this thing (`quantityInput.value`), turning it into a number, and comparing it to another number. Of course it's more verbose, but in the last example, we're only up by 4 characters.

### Magic is bad, mkay?

Double equals becomes less predictable when you start comparing things that might not be primitives.

Take this example:

```
var a = 'aString';
var b = {
    toString: function() {
        return 'aString';
    }
};

a == b; // true
```

You may have been expecting that for the double equals, the compare would invoke `b`'s `toString` to compare `a`'s string value, and you were right.

But what about this?:

```
var a = 'aString';
var b = {
    valueOf: function() {
        return 'aDifferentString';
    },
    toString: function() {
        return 'aString';
    }
};

a == b; // 'aString' == 'aDifferentString' // false
```

`valueOf` trampled `toString`. Double equals doesn't care what types you're comparing. If it sees a primitive being compared with an object, it'll try for `valueOf` first, and `toString` second.

What about when `a` is the number `0`, and `b.valueOf` returns a `'0'` string?:

```
var a = 0;
var b = {
    toString: function() {
        return '0';
    }
};

a == b; // 0 == '0' // 0 === 0 // true
```

The double equals used `b.toString` which provided a `String`, and then casted that `String` to a `Number`.

Now what if `a` and `b` are both objects that return the same thing in `valueOf` and `toString`?

```
var a = {
    valueOf: function() {
        return 'aValue';
    },
    toString: function() {
        return 'aString';
    }
};
var b = {
    valueOf: function() {
        return 'aValue';
    },
    toString: function() {
        return 'aString';
    }
};

a == b; // false
```

Were you expecting that? If not, this should serve as a good example as to why **magic is bad**. You never know how powerful the magic is going to be.

In this case, because neither `a` nor `b` were primitives, it skipped the `valueOf` and `toString` calls, and simply compared pointers.

---

EDIT: I'll add one "useful" case where a former co-worker violated his own "always use triple equals" rule from the project code spec that he drafted.

He'd check for `undefined` using `potentiallyUndefinedThing == null`. His argument was that it should get special treatment because double equals equates null to undefined and it kills two birds with one stone (`undefined` & `null` checks). In reality, nearly every case he used it, we all knew that the value would either never be `null` or never be `undefined`. Just because you see a tweet suggesting a use of `==` doesn't make the magic kosher. It's still just laziness.

It didn't bother me too much when I reviewed his code, but when he sent back my explicit `=== undefined` checks to be replaced with `== null` checks, I cringed.

Comment: :P _"lower the bar for people learning the language"_

Answer (score 1):

=== checks the datatype also,but while using == its check the value only.
ie;if(2=='2') it return true.but if we use (2==='2') it return false.
Hope you understand.

Better use === always

Answer (score 0):

The identical operator `===` and the equality `==` operator are identical except the fact that there is no type conversion is done in identical operator `===`.

For ex:

`12.01 == "12.01" // will be true`

`12.01 === "12.01" // will be false`